# C# Weird Bug when trying to remove Controls from Group Box

Tags: c#, controls, groupbox, removeall

I am currently facing a really weird issue. I simply want to remove all controls from a group box, but it just does not remove all controls. It really seems like a bug on Microsoft's end right now. I tried many different techniques of removing these controls, but none of them worked. I have two other methods where I am removing just one Control at a time (and no, I cannot call that in a loop for all my controls) and there it works fine. I have no idea what the issue could be. Hopefully someone knows a way around this.

```
foreach (Control c in fieldBox.Controls) // this does not work, it only removes my labels (I have one txt and one lbl)
                fieldBox.Controls.Remove(c);

            for (int i = 0; i < fieldBox.Controls.Count; i++) // this does not work either
                fieldBox.Controls.Remove(fieldBox.Controls[i]);

            for (int i = 0; i < fieldBox.Controls.Count; i++) // still no success
                fieldBox.Controls.RemoveAt(i);

            for (int i = 0; i < fieldBox.Controls.Count; i++) // nope
                fieldBox.Controls.RemoveByKey(fieldBox.Controls[i].Name);

            foreach (Control c in fieldBox.Controls) // my final answer, but the outcome did not change
                fieldBox.Controls.RemoveByKey(c.Name);
```

Comment: What is the result of fieldBox.Controls.Count?

Comment: What does `does not work` mean?  Is an error thrown?  Modifying a collection while looping it usually fails.  Best to store the control, then remove it after.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose Six which is correct, but I also looked at it in a loop and somehow it decreases to four and then randomly stops.

Comment: @paqogomez No, but it does not remove all the controls, only half of them.

Comment: Consider that your index is incrementing while the size of the collection is decrementing.  Half seems about right.

Comment: @paqogomez Not too sure how to solve it though. I thought about that as well, but I thought the foreach loop would deal with that accordingly. I do not really want to loop through everything again since that would not really be very efficient. Is there same other way of doing it?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose's solution will work perfectly.

Comment: Okay, I should simply use a while loop. That should solve it.

Comment: ?!?!?! what?  Nothing about @PraveenPaulose's solution says "while loop"

Comment: Oh right, did not see that without refreshing. I'll try both methods.

Comment: With a while loop you will still end doing more iterations than are needed.  With @PraveenPaulose's solution, you will start at the top and remove down to the bottom and be done.  Very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try decreasing the counter and removing controls

```
for (int i = fieldBox.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) // hopefully successful
            fieldBox.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
```